# C++ how to allocate memory to a pointer of a struct which is member of another second struct?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is the code:

```
# include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
    struct hub
    {
        int info;
        int info2;
    };
    struct hub2
    {
        hub *p;
    };
    int main()
    {
        hub *pi;
        pi = new hub; // allocate memory for pi
        pi->info = 30;
        pi->info2 = 45;
        cout<<pi->info<<" "<<pi->info2; // shows 30 and 45
        hub2 obj; // declare a hub2 data type
        obj.p = new hub; // allocate memory for obj.p
        obj.p = pi; // now obj.p should be identical to what pi points to right?
        cout<<"\n"<<obj.p->info<<" "<<obj.p->info2; // This will show 30 and 45
        cout<<endl;
        delete pi;
        cout<<"\n"<<obj.p->info<<" "<<obj.p->info2;//This shows random numbers,why ???
    }
```

Why doesn't obj.p allocate memory after I delete the memory allocated for pi pointer?
I really need a solution to this.I have to finish a very important project and I am stuck here with at this memory allocating part :(

Comment: You've deleted the object that `obj.p` points to, it is now a dangling pointer pointing to unallocated (or potentially re-used) memory.

Comment: If you want to copy values (because you allocated `obj.p = new hub;` too), use more `*`. Ie. `obj.*p = *pi;`. And delete the second new-ed thing too sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
obj.p = pi; // now obj.p should be identical to what pi points to right?
```

Yes, both pointers are now equal. As a consequence, `delete pi` is equivalent to `delete obj.p`. Once this is done, the statement

```
cout<<"\n"<<obj.p->info<<" "<<obj.p->info2;//This shows random numbers,why ???
```

tries to access the memory which has just been freed. This results in undefined behavior.

As a side note, be careful here:

```
obj.p = new hub; // allocate memory for obj.p
obj.p = pi;
```

The second statement *overwrites* the pointer to the memory allocated by `new hub`. After that, such memory is no longer accessible, nor can be freed. This is a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

obj.p = new hub; // Not necessary ,you can directly  write   obj.p = pi

delete pi; //After  this instruction,  pi  is  free (BUT NOT AUTOMATICALLY  TO NULL  ) pi points  now  to  a "trash" ,  it's  why you see  random  number.
So  you have to reallocate  it again .